# sql injection prevention for create method in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

As seen in comment_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
end
```

Im assuming that this is SQL injection-unsafe. But what is the correct way of doing it?.. All the examples on the net deal with finds.

Answer (score 7):

That code **is** safe from SQL injection attacks. The escaping is done by ActiveRecord, so any time you call a model's `find`, `create`, `new`/`save`, or any other method that does database interaction, you're OK. The only exception is if you use raw SQL for one of the options, for example:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => "user_id = #{params[:user_id]}")
```

the preferred form is:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => params[:user_id]})
```

which will be automatically protected against SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your code example is safe from SQL injection as explained by Alex, but it's not safe from [mass assignment exploits](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Comment: Very good point - not sure why this hasn't occurred to me before