# rails is Model.new safe from sql injection?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Does ModelName.new protect against sql injection?

Example:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])

@user.save
```

I've read the [rails security doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)s and didn't see anything about inserts via Model.new.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model.new` has nothing to do with SQL injection as it is not the method that writes to the database . 
It is the `Model.save` that actually writes to the database and takes care of SQL injection .

Comment: you mean if i assign value individually and then use `Model.save` it will take care of SQL injection. if Yes, `you are wrong`

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144778/sql-injection-prevention-for-create-method-in-rails-controller . And http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment .

Comment: @NM - so ANY .save is always safe from injection? Since you can't do raw SQL with .save? Also, mass assignment has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @bandhunt - Take a look at this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment . Mass assignment has a role to play in this as someone might corrupt the hash that is passed to the new method and hence overwrite database values . So it is always a good practice to whitelist your mass assignment variables through attr_accessible . Hope that helps .

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I have a whitelist in my model is what I was trying to say. I was just wondering about sql injection right now.

Answer (score 0):

`yes` it protect against sql injection and is safe as params[:user] is HASH

you can check it with follwing example i assumr you get some invalid values in params[:user][:name]

```
  @user= User.new(params[:user])

  @user.save
```

AND

```
  @user= User.new()
  @user.name=params[:user][:name]  #your application may crash here or this is not sql injection safe
  @user.save
```

To avoid this you can use hash

```
  @user= User.new({:name=>params[:user][:name]})
  @user.save
```

**After  reading [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#_sql_injection) i came to conlcusion neither .new & .save are safe from sql injection**

```
Edited
```

The mass-assignment feature may become a problem, as it allows an attacker to set any model’s attributes by manipulating the hash passed to a model’s new() method:

PLEASE READ `6 Mass Assignment` for it's Problems and `6.1 Countermeasures` for solution

Comment: can you explain why  the former is safer than the latter? thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any rails docs that explain this? I know the security docs talk about find, but not about create/save.

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment . What you are saying is completely the opposite of what Rails security docs say .